# Timing diagram and performance of Binary Counters

Tags: counter, digital-communications

I have a binary counter which is the following :
https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc14020b-d.pdf

[image]

I want to reset this counter with a signal. I want this signal to be the narrower, ie the length of the pulse to be minimum. But I have to verify that the narrower signal is still took into account by the counter. I imagine that the the length of the pulse cannot be as small as I want. There is a mention about "Reset pulse width" into the datasheet but I do not know if it is that data that I have to consider and if there are other parameters to consider. I do not want to take any risks

[image]

-----------------------------------E D I T --------------------------------------

Here is a better binary counters  :
https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/308/1/MC74HC4020A_D-2315492.pdf

[image]

The reset pulse width is lower as the reset recovery time compared to the MC14020B but what is strange is that the maximum input rise time is very large ? What does "Maximum input Rise and Fall times" ? Does I have to consider that my pulse needs to be superior to the reset pulse width + the reset recovery time + the rise/fall time ?

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Yes, that is the requirement you must meet. Note the huge discrepancy between minimum and typical values.

Comment: @DaveTweed I found a better binary counter but there is still an information that I do not get. Could you please help me ? See my edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When speed matters, you won’t want to use 4xxx family high voltage logic and choose a family with a lower maximum  Vdd.

The reasons for this is that newer, much smaller channels, have lower breakdown voltage, lower capacitance, lower RdsOn like 50 ohms for 74HCxx vs ~300 to 3k ohms for 4xxx family (18V to 3V) which on the CMOS drivers work fine but slower.

In your case you want to consider the largest pulse width, & recovery time and also derate for case temperatures above 25’C where they run slower due to higher RdsOn.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a better binary counter but there is still an information that I do not get. Could you please help me ? See my edited post

Comment: Huh? Max rise time means slow on input, not output.  
That’s irrelevant

Comment: That's mean I must apply a signal faster than rise/fall time specified ?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: If you’re still concerned about speed , try the LV4060 which includes a clock rated for 100MHz @ 3V https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/74LV4060-1598056.pdf